# Custom domain is not accepted by Branch after setting the correct ns records

Tags: dns, branch, deep-linking, branch.io

I want to use branch.io fro deep-linking but my custom domain doesn't register with the service.

At link settings, where I define my custom link I have this message:

```
Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your NS record. A CNAME record is not required. If you've already done this, note that it can take up to several hours to propagate.
ns-1104.awsdns-10.org.
ns-19.awsdns-02.com.
ns-666.awsdns-19.net.
ns-1742.awsdns-25.co.uk.
```

And this is how I've set it up in my domain settings (goDaddy):

[image]

I've done this about 3-4 days ago. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the domain name?

Comment: Yes it's republicera.co

Comment: Yoor nameservers are configured correctly (at GoDaddy), something else is wrong

Comment: Thanks Dusan, I'll try to reach branch support. That's a new domain and a new branch project so I haven't done anything else that might explain it on my side

Comment: Is there a public URL to their instruction on how to set up DNS, so I can take a look?

Comment: I'll dig more into the documents and report back, but in the surface there weren't any instructions other then directing the ns as by the notes I've attached.

Comment: Well, name servers are not of much use unless they contain DNS records...

Comment: @DusanBajic Hi Dusan, just an update, I opened branch again this morning and the message was gone. I'm in Australia so haven't changed anything in the last 10 hours. Looks like it just takes a long time for it to register with them, not sure why, but looks like it's alright now. Thanks for the help.